# Admob error android:configChanges in Eclipse and Device

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

Eclipse is giving me an error on the android:configChanges line in my AndroidManifest.xml:
**"< activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">"**

**the error is:**

error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').

If I leave only keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation there's no error, but compiler asks for the 4 remaining ones when I try and build. But there is no ads displayed.

I'm using GoogleAdMobAdsSDK-4.3.1.
If i set project.properties target-13.my android 2.3 device does not run the app..But my device run so many app that having ads are displayed..

Please Help me..!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need do this:

> The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires Android 1.5 or later. Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (**set target in default.properties to android-13**).

Comment: If I set android-13. My app doesnt run on android 2.3. It converts to android 3.2(13 API). My problem is " how can I create and run in android 2.3 "

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this blog post](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/migrating-to-v431-of-admob-sdk-for.html).  You need to set android-13 for 4.3.1 to compile, but you can use

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
```

or any version down to 3, and your app will then run on your 2.3 device.

Comment: If i set android-13. then it will automatically converted to Android 3.2. so it cant run on android 2.3

Comment: So when setting `android-13` in project.properties, then Android 3.2 is just the library that the app will "compile" against.  But you decide on what versions of Android your app runs on by using the [<uses-sdk>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) element in your AndroidManifest file.  If you're using Eclipse, ignore the red `X` you get when you try to run it.  That is just a warning meaning your device has a different API level than the `targetSdkVersion`.